# Unable to create a 'DbContext' of type ''

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, database, asp.net-web-api

I try to migrate the model to mysql using this command here

```
dotnet ef migrations add InitialCreate
```

but the exception was thrown here and error was occured

```
Unable to create a 'DbContext' of type ''. The exception 'Host 'XXX' is not allowed to connect to this MariaDB server' was thrown while attempting to create an instance. For the different patterns supported at design time, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728
```

this is my datacontext.cs, im using mysql in localhost with default password and username, i
just followed the tutorial how to Connect to MySQL Database with Entity Framework Core

```
using fixit.Models;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace fixit.Data

{
    
    public class DataContext : DbContext
    {
        protected readonly IConfiguration Configuration;

    public DataContext(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder options)
    {
        // connect to mysql with connection string from app settings
        var connectionString = Configuration.GetConnectionString("WebApiDatabase");
        options.UseMySql(connectionString, ServerVersion.AutoDetect(connectionString));
    }
        public DataContext() { }
        public DataContext(DbContextOptions<DataContext> options) : base(options) { }

            public DbSet<Service> Service { get; set; }
        
        }
}
```

and this is my program.cs, mostly this code is from startup.cs in .Net 5, since it has been deprecated, i convert the code to program.cs

```
using fixit.Data;
using fixit.Models;
using Microsoft.Data.SqlClient;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);



// Add services to the container

builder.Services.AddDbContext<DataContext>(opt => opt.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("AZURE_SQL_CONNECTIONSTRING")));
builder.Services.AddAutoMapper(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies());
builder.Services.AddCors(option =>
            {
                option.AddPolicy("allowedOrigin",
                    builder => builder.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader()
                    );
            });
builder.Services.AddControllers();
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddScoped<IRepository<Service>, ServiceRepository>();
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
}

app.UseCors(builder => builder
       .AllowAnyHeader()
       .AllowAnyMethod()
       .AllowAnyOrigin()
    );
app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
});

app.Run();
```

this is my appsetting.json

```
{

  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "WebApiDatabase": "server=localhost; database=test; user=root; password= ;"
},

  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"

}
```

how to solve this?

Comment: can take a peek on `appsettings` json file? make sure these are correct: *"im using mysql in localhost with default **password** and **username**"*

Comment: @BagusTesa i have edited the post, appsettings.json has added

Comment: try remove `password= ;` entirely. your whitespace might be considered as password and afaik no password in mysql is different from empty password.

Answer (score 2):

I saw in your program.cs file still using SQL Server for EF Core.

```
builder.Services.AddDbContext<DataContext>(opt => opt.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("AZURE_SQL_CONNECTIONSTRING")));
```

If you are using mysql you should change according to that.

```
builder.Services.AddDbContext<DataContext>(opt => opt.UseMySql(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("WebApiDatabase"), ServerVersion.AutoDetect(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("WebApiDatabase"))));
```

You should import Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql top of the program.cs file this.

```
using Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql;
```